# Why am I getting a 400 Bad Request if I send payload with \n?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a request as such

```
RestClient::Request.execute({
      method: :post,
      url: url,
      headers: headers.merge(content_type: :json),
      timeout: 5,
      payload: { value: value }.to_json
    })
```

if my value variable contain a new line char such as "Hi\n\nHey" i get a 400 bad request error. If I don't have the new line char \n it works fine such as "Hi".

Comment: There isn’t enough information here. Of course Google.com won’t let you post to it.

Comment: @JoshBrody I am posting to an api endpoint of a lambda function. I know it is able to post because if I send the payload without the new line chars, it works

Comment: The 400 error code is generated by the server. Therefore we need to know more about the server config and the code running on the server.

Comment: Or at least the full response.